# convergence, contracting sequence

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I need a little help on the following question:

let $x(0)$ be an element of reals and define a sequence $\{x(n)\}$ by:
$x(1) =f(x(0)), x(2)=f(x(1)),...., x(n+1)= f(x(n))...$

show that if $m>0, n\geq 0$ then
$$|x(n+m)-x(n)|<\frac{1}{1-K}|x(n+1)-x(n)|, \quad \text{for some} \quad 0<k\leq 1$$
Show that the sequence converges

I've first assumed that there exist a $K$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|< k|x-y|$ and worked out on that assumption,concluding that $|x(m+n)-x(n)|< \frac{1-k^{n+1}}{1-k} |x(n+1)-x(n)|$. I could not reach the answer given.

To show that the sequence converges, I've been thinking about using the definition for cauchy convergence, or show that the sequence is contracting but unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to express it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need your map $f$ to be a contraction, I think. Note that you need $k < 1$, otherwise $1/(1-k)$ would be negative. Finally, note that $$\frac{1-k^{n+1}}{1-k} < \frac{1}{1-k}$$

Comment: yeah, I made a typo.. in fact, k lies between 0 and 1( o included but not 1).